# Functional role of element within power op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I came across this op-amp circuit on an applications page for driving piezo transducers, and I am not certain of the purpose of R5 and C5 in the schematic.

[image: circuit diag]

My understanding of the circuit is that it is that the voltage swing seen at Vout is double the voltage input swing (assuming R1=R2=R3=R4) due to 180 degree out-of phase relationship of the output between the two inverting amplifiers.

My guess is that the benefit to this circuit is that you get twice the voltage swing at the output with half input voltage rail. However, what purpose do R5 and C5 serve in the circuit?

If this helps:

1. The original circuit was a general outline of a circuit and the grounds were placed there by me. If placement of ground in the schematic makes this circuit nonsensical, this would be helpful to know.
2. The op-amps eluded to in the aforementioned sketch are power op-amps designed to drive high voltage/current.

Comment: damped low-pass filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Survey says...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJwZE0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: LPF]